# Specifying dependencies between SUBDIRS projects with .depends doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm having problems setting up dependencies between subprojects in the context of a qmake `SUBDIRS` project.

I'm using the `.depends` option to establish the dependency of one project on another, expecting the former to be recompiled when the latter is modified, but this doesn't happen - the latter is recompiled after the modification, but the dependent project is not.

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of the `.depends` option?

Here's a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
+mysubdirs/
| mysubdirs.pro
| +mylib/
| | mylib.pro
| | MyClass.h
| | MyClass.cpp
| +myapp/
| | myapp.pro
| | main.cpp
```

**mysubdirs.pro**:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += mylib
SUBDIRS += myapp
CONFIG += ordered
myapp.depends = mylib
```

**mylib.pro**:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
HEADERS = MyClass.h
SOURCES = MyClass.cpp
```

**myapp.pro**:

```
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES = main.cpp
LIBS += "../../build-mysubdirs/mylib/libmylib.a"
INCLUDEPATH += ../mylib
```

**MyClass.h**:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
};
#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**MyClass.cpp**:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    std::cout << "in constructor" << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
int main()
{
    MyClass x;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the subdirs project. Then change the string "in constructor" to something else and recompile: the output of myapp is unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding the meaning of the .depends option?

Yes, you are.

Basically, `qmake` is a "Makefile"-generator. And ".depends" here means "a dependency in a generated Makefile". So `myapp.depends = mylib` becomes `myapp: mylib` in a root Makefile.

However, both `mylib` and `myapp` (being `SUBDIRS`) are just `.PHONY` targets which perform recursive make invocations. So, at the end of the day, make will run two sub-makes, which absolutely do not depend on each other (as it's usual with a recursive make pattern), except one sub-make always runs before the other (because of a target-prerequisite relation in a root Makefile).

By the way, it means that `CONFIG += ordered` makes no sense here and should be omitted (in fact, it's deprecated in favour of `.depends`).

Now, considering recompilation of `myapp`: it turns out that your executable **DOES NOT** depend on your library (in a "make-sense"), except that library is mentioned in `$$LIBS` (i.e. linker flags). To fix this issue you have to add your library to the application target dependency list manually:

> myapp.pro

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += path/to/mylib.a
```

Comment: "Adding libraries to Qt Projects" at https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html describes how Qt Creator can add everything you need for all platforms of interest, whether statically or dynamically linked, with a Wizard. Once you have used the Wizard a few times, you figure it out and can copy-and-paste, if you prefer.